# Filtering two arrays to avoid Inf/NaN values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two arrays of doubles of the same size, containg X and Y values for some plots.

I need to create some kind of protection against INF/NaN values. I need to find all that pairs of values (X, Y) for which both, X and Y are not INF nor NaN

If I have one array, I can do it using lambdas:

```
var filteredValues = someValues.Where(d=> !(double.IsNaN(d) || double.IsInfinity(d))).ToList();
```

Now, for two arrays I use the following loop:

```
List<double> filteredX=new List<double>();
List<double> filteredY=new List<double>();

for(int i=0;i<XValues.Count;i++)
{
   if(!double.IsNan(XValues[i]) &&
         !double.IsInfinity(XValues[i]) &&
         !double.IsNan(YValues[i]) &&
         !double.IsInfinity(YValues[i]) )
     {
       filteredX.Add(XValues[i]);
       filteredY.Add(YValues[i]);
     }
}
```

Is there a way of filtering two arrays at the same time using LINQ/lambdas, as it was done for the single array?

Unfortunately I can use only .NET 3.5.

Comment: slight error in your declaration.  filteredX is declared twice.  I'm sure you meant filteredY for one of them.  :D

Comment: What you seek is quite doable in .NET 3.5. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slight correction for Mark's original answer:

```
var filteredValues = XValues.Zip(YValues, (x,y) => new { x, y })
        .Where(p => !(double.IsNan(p.x) || double.IsNan(p.y) || 
                      double.IsInfinity(p.x) || double.IsInfinity(p.y)))
        .ToList();
```

Alternatively, you might want to make it slightly neater:

```
Func<double, bool> valid = z => !double.IsNan(z) && !double.IsInfinity(z);
var filteredValues = XValues.Zip(YValues, (x,y) => new { x, y })
        .Where(p => valid(p.x) && valid(p.y))
        .ToList();
```

If you then need the results back into two lists, you can do:

```
var filteredX = filteredValues.Select(p => p.x).ToList();
var filteredY = filteredValues.Select(p => p.y).ToList();
```

Comment: I guess there should be IsInfinity instead of second IsNan in your valid Func declaration? 
Unfortunately I cannot use 4.0 (see edit), but thanks anyway

Comment: @Gacek: Yes, that should be IsInfinity; fixed. You can get the Zip operator from MoreLINQ too: http://morelinq.googlecode.com

Comment: Thanks, I probably will. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

C# 4.0 introduces the [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method to accomplish iterating over enumerables "in parallel" as you describe.

I haven't used it myself, but it should be something like:

```
var filteredValues = 
   XValues.Zip(YValues, (x,y) => new { X = x, Y = y})
        .Where( o =>
          !(double.IsNan(o.X) || double.IsNan(o.Y) || double.IsInfinity(o.X) || double.IsInfinity(o.Y)))
            .ToList();
```

(Sorry for the funny indentation, wanted it to be more readable on SO)

Comment: Zip has no predicate in it, just a lambda that converts x and y into some single value.

Comment: Nice one. I wish I could use 4.0 (sorry I forgot to write it in my question).

Comment: @Gacek: Nothing's stopping you from writing your *own* `Zip` extension ! See my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you can't use .NET 4.0 and therefore can't use the Zip extension.

Or *can* you?

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    using (var eFirst = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var eSecond = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (eFirst.MoveNext() && eSecond.MoveNext())
            yield return resultSelector(eFirst.Current, eSecond.Current);
    }
}
```

See for yourself :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, double.NaN, 4.0, 5.0 };
    var y = new double[] { 0.5, 1.5, double.PositiveInfinity, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5 };

    // note: using KeyValuePair<double, double> --
    // you could just as easily use your own custom type
    // (probably a simple struct)
    var zipped = x.Zip(y, (a, b) => new KeyValuePair<double, double>(a, b))
        .Where(kvp => IsValid(kvp.Key) && IsValid(kvp.Value))
        .ToList();

    foreach (var z in zipped)
        Console.WriteLine("X: {0}, Y: {1}", z.Key, z.Value);
}

static bool IsValid(double value)
{
    return !double.IsNaN(value) && !double.IsInfinity(value);
}
```

Output:

```
X: 0, Y: 0.5
X: 1, Y: 1.5
X: 4, Y: 4.5
X: 5, Y: 5.5
```

Comment: Thanks, great example of creating extensions. It can help me some day ;) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

> ```
> doubleArray1.Zip(doubleArray2, (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y))
>             .Where(tup => !double.IsNaN(tup.Item1) &&
>             !double.IsNaN(tup.Item2) &&
>             !double.IsInfinity(tup.Item1) &&
>             !double.IsInfinity(tup.Item1));
> ```

Alternately, you could make a method for filtering and zipping at the same time, the major benefit is that you're not limited to C# 4:

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TOne, TTwo>> DualWhere<TOne, TTwo>(this IEnumerable<TOne> one, IEnumerable<TTwo> two, Func<TOne, TTwo, bool> predicate)
> {
>     var oneEnumerator = one.GetEnumerator();
>     var twoEnumerator = two.GetEnumerator();
>     while (oneEnumerator.MoveNext() && twoEnumerator.MoveNext())
>     {
>         if (predicate(oneEnumerator.Current, twoEnumerator.Current))
>             yield return Tuple.Create(oneEnumerator.Current, twoEnumerator.Current);
>     }
>     oneEnumerator.Dispose();
>     twoEnumerator.Dispose();
> }
> ```

**Edit:** The latter should work with C# 3.5.

Comment: I think you mean .NET 3.5. There's no such thing as C# 3.5. You should use using statements instead of manually calling Dispose though. Note that nothing in the existing answers required *C# 4* - it just requires *.NET 4*, as does your answer - because it uses Tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work in C# 3 and .NET 3.5

```
List<double> list1 = new List<double>() { 1.2, 3.8, double.NaN, 17.8 };
List<double> list2 = new List<double>() { 9.4, double.PositiveInfinity, 10.4, 26.2 };

var query = from x in list1.Select((item, idx) => new { item, idx })
            where !double.IsNaN(x.item) && !double.IsInfinity(x.item)
            join y in list2.Select((item, idx) => new { item, idx })
            on x.idx equals y.idx
            where !double.IsNaN(y.item) && !double.IsInfinity(y.item)
            select new { X = x.item, Y = y.item };
```

Iterating over the query would produce pairs containing 1.2 & 9.4 and 17.8 & 26.2. The middle two pairs would be discarded because one contains NaN and the other contains infinity.

```
foreach (var pair in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", pair.X, pair.Y);
}
```